# Can I use push-pull/source ordering in Foundation to achieve this layout?

Tags: responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to create a responsive layout using the [Zurb Foundation 4 Grid](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/grid.html), and having a difficult time wrapping my head around how I could possibly create a column layout using push-pull that orders content properly in both mobile and desktop without having to resort to javascript or duplicating data in "hide-for-small/hide-for-large" classed DIVs.

Following the "mobile first" philosophy, let's say that I have the following desired layout for an event site:

Mobile:

```
12 columns
========================
[Name / Date / Location]
[Photo                 ]
[Event details         ]
[Attendees             ]
[RSVP                  ]
[Edit link             ]
```

Desktop:

```
4 columns          8 columns
=============================================
[Photo     ]    |   [Name / Date / Location ]
[RSVP      ]    |   [Event details          ]
[Edit Link ]    |   [Attendees              ]
```

How can I format the HTML so that it would display in the proper order in both circumstances?

Right now, I'm doing this for mobile:

```
<!-- note: there are many ways to create this layout -
           it could be in sets of individual rows as well -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="small-12 columns">
      <div class="namedatelocation">(name/date/location html)</div>
  </div>
  <div class="small-12 columns">
      <div class="photo">(photo html)</div>
  </div>
  <div class="small-12 columns">
      <div class="details">(details html)</div>
  </div>
  <div class="small-12 columns">
      <div class="attendees">(attendees html)</div>
  </div>
  <div class="small-12 columns">
      <div class="rsvp">(rsvp html)</div>
  </div>
  <div class="small-12 columns">
      <div class="edit">(edit html)</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And I can do this for desktop:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-4 columns">
      <div class="photo">(photo html)</div>
      <div class="rsvp">(rsvp html)</div>
      <div class="edit">(edit html)</div>
  </div>
  <div class="large-8 columns">
      <div class="namedatelocation">(name/date/location html)</div>
      <div class="details">(details html)</div>
      <div class="attendees">(attendees html)</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I create this content in a responsive manner?  The best I've been able to accomplish so far is to break the content into "pairs" and put each pair into its own row with push-pull used to change the order of the 2 columns inside the row.  The issue with this approach, besides the limitation of only reordering pairs - is that the height of each row is equal to the tallest of the two columns in that row.  This means that there's a huge amount of dead space in the desktop layout.

Any ideas on how I could accomplish what I'm trying to do?  Or is it not possible in Foundation?  If not, what would be the proper way to address this problem in general?

Answer (score 2):

You can still use the push and pull classes similar to how they are used in F3. You can read the Source Ordering section on [Foundation's doc page](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/grid.html). Here's how you can solve your problem:

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="large-8 push-4 small-12 columns">
          <div class="namedatelocation">(name/date/location html)</div>
      </div>
      <div class="large-4 pull-8 small-12 columns">
          <div class="photo">(photo html)</div>
      </div>
      <div class="large-8 push-4 small-12 columns">
          <div class="details">(details html)</div>
      </div>
        <div class="large-4 pull-8 small-12 columns rsvp">
          <div class="rsvp">(rsvp html)</div>
      </div>
      <div class="large-8 push-4 small-12 columns attendees">
          <div class="attendees">(attendees html)</div>
      </div>

      <div class="large-4 pull-8 small-12 columns">
          <div class="edit">(edit html)</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Now that's for desktop, the tricky part is how you will show it for mobile. Take note that I tackle the desktop first as the pull and push can tackle your desktop views easier. To layout your mobile view you need to do some css and there's actually no Foundation way of doing it, not that I know of. For the solution, say for example and I assume you have a "defined height" for your divs, and that the height is set to 30px, you can add the following style:

```
.row .small-12.rsvp {
    margin-top: 30px;
}
.row .small-12.attendees {
    margin-top: -30px;
}
```

NOTE: Notice I added the classes `rsvp` and `attendees` to the two small-12 divs, fourth and fifth divs respectively.